# What will happen to custom woocommerce functions, If i update woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have developed a custom woocommerce function to retrieve vendor list. I just want to know what will happen to the custom function I developed, If i update woocommerce ?

Answer (score 1):

check following two case

1.) in this if you have override woo-commerce function in your child theme function.php and not make any change in woo-commerce plugin you don't have to worry about update woo-commerce.

2.) in this if you have do same as point 1 but this time woo-commerce deprecate the same function which you used in function.php in this case we have not any other solution rather than having create new one.

3.) and last if you have make change in woo-commerce plugin folder and you have to doing update woo-commerce it lost whole your setting and you have to sit for new settings in it.

now match your case with following and check for updating woo-commerce or not in our case.

**Thank You.**

Comment: Thank you @Niket Joshi for your response